# MacbookPro - does it have an HDMI port

Tags: hdmi

The official [website](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-pro/apdfb31396d3/mac) says:

> Note: Mac Pro has at least one HDMI 2.0 port and four Thunderbolt 3
> (USB-C) ports.

Is it meant for all generic MacBook pros? Because I don't see an HDMI port on my mac. Where exactly is it located? Is the documentation wrong?

Comment: Mac Pro != MacBook Pro

Answer (score 1):

You are quoting from the spec page for a Mac Pro, not the MacBook Pro.  The Mac Pro certainly has a HDMI port.

The MacBook Pro **may** have one, depending on which one you have.

The most recent one does not, in either 13" or 16" sizes.

https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-16/specs/